# Duplicate xml column insert

Tags: sql, xml, xquery-sql

I have a table that stores an XML data type. I'm trying to compare what is in the table against data that will be inserted.

How do I Query and compare a sql XML data type to a table XML column?

---

I converted the data column to a varchar and did a string compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted the data column to a varchar and did a string compare.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you could compare CLOB's by using **[dbms_lob.compare](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i1016668)**